# Angular 2 Quickstart with NPM 3.10.6,node@v4.5.0

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm

all get when do NPM start is [image: All get is the loading the my-app component is not working]

Here are my files
**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",

  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.6.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.17",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.18",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.3.2"
  }
}
```

**tsCongig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
```

**typing.jason**

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160807145350"
  }
}
```

**systemjs.connfig.json**

```
* Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {

  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',

    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };

  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];

  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
     <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**styles.css**

```
/* Master Styles */
h1 {
  color: #369;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 250%;
}
h2, h3 {
  color: #444;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
body {
  margin: 2em;
}
```

if some on could help with this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Check browser console for any errors.

Comment: what error do you get in console? try running local host on chrome browser

Comment: `main.ts` is there inside `app` folder?

Comment: yes there is see my answer though @PankajParkar getting the node_modules setup properly made the other two errors be shown

Answer (score 0):

oops named systemjs.config.js wrongly missed some code out of app.module.ts  but my main problem was the set up I had to reset node_modules and updated peers not installed